# Deny AWS S3 bucket access for 2 users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have little to no knowledge writing JavaScript so I need a little help please.

I have created several buckets on my AWS account along with a few users.  I know the correct syntax to write for denying a specific user access to a bucket but I need to deny access to two users. I do not know the correct syntax to do that :(

I have the following two users: `BarnU` and `BarnZ`

The code I have for denying access to one user is as follow:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1575527937316",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1575527932225",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::755268545265:user/BarnU"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::poloserver/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I add to this script the user `BarnZ`?

Thank you

Comment: Use an array for the two IAM user ARNs, or simply add two statements, one per IAM user.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply list them using `[ ]` notation:

```
"AWS": [
    "arn:aws:iam::755268545265:user/BarnU", 
    "arn:aws:iam::755268545265:user/BarnZ"
]
```

Full policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1575527937316",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1575527932225",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::755268545265:user/BarnU", 
                    "arn:aws:iam::755268545265:user/BarnZ"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::poloserver/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks but sadly I now get:  Policy has invalid principal

Comment: Are you sure that these users exist? Note that the names are case sensitive. If you are getting this error then it means that the policy has been correctly parsed but the mentioned user(s) do not exist in your account.

Answer (score 1):

When applying policies for specific users, it is recommended to **put the policies against the actual IAM Users themselves**, or an IAM Group.

- Rules that affect everybody should go in the **bucket policy** (eg making the whole bucket public)
- Rules that affect a specific user should go in the **IAM User**
- Rules that affect a group of users (eg Admins) should go in an **IAM Group**, which is then assigned to the IAM Users

Also, if possible, it is better to avoid using `Deny` policies and instead limit the policies that initially `Allow` the access. By default, nobody has access to anything in Amazon S3. You must have some policy that is granting these two users access to S3. If possible, simply limit the access being granted in these `Allow` policies so they were never granted access in the first place.

Where you have a situation that somebody receives a permission but you wish to *override* that permissions, use a `Deny`. For example, somebody might be granted access to all Amazon S3 buckets, but you do not want them to access two buckets containing sensitive data. In this situation, you can use a `Deny` policy to override the `Allow`.

To do this, put the policy shown in your question against the specific IAM User(s), but **leave out the `Principal` section** because it will automatically apply against the IAM User(s) that have been assigned the policy.

- Create an Inline Policy against the desired Users
- Deny them access to the bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, make sure these users do not have IAM permissions that allows them to change their own policy, otherwise they can change/remove the policy.